# How to use `If` function in `arrayformula` in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following function

```
 =IF(A2 <=10 , "YES","NO")
```

And if I want to apply for the entire column I have to drag this formula down. However, I wish to make it automated. The following formula doesn't work

```
={"New column";arrayformula(IF(A2 <=10 , "YES","NO"))}
```

Is there any way that I can make this formula automated for the entire column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of arrayformula should have an array somewhere. For example: A2:A instead of A2.

```
={"New column"; arrayformula(IF(A2:A <=10 , "YES", "NO"))}
```